# Why is Django not displaying all attributes of an object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the problem that I have a model with two fields, but only one is shown in the output.

I have this code in my views.py

```
class Update_Org(UpdateView):
    model = OrgKlass
    form_class = form_update_org
    template_name = templ_folder_name + 'update_org.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy(url_app_name + 'list_org')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        self.queryset = OrgKlass.objects.get(id = self.to_update)
        return self.queryset

    def post(self, request, pk):
        if self.request.POST.get('action', False) == 'update':
            self.to_update = pk
            self.object = self.get_object()
            print(self.object.ok_beschreibung)
            return super(Update_Org, self).post(request, pk)
        else:
            pass # because I do not need that right now
```

The form looks like this:

```
class form_update_org(forms.ModelForm):
    ok_bezeichnung = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Org-Bezeichnung", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',}))
    ok_beschreibung = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Beschreibung des Tätigkeitsfeldes des Bereichs", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control',}))

    class Meta:
        model = OrgKlass
        fields = ('ok_bezeichnung', 'ok_beschreibung')
```

And this is part of the html template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for label, value in object.get_fields %}
    label: {{label}}<br>
    value: {{value}}<br>
    {% endfor %}                                                
{% endblock %}
```

The output however looks like this:

```
label: ID
value: 9
label: Org-Bezeichnung
value: Company A
label: Beschreibung des Tätigkeitsfeldes
value:
```

However, if you look at the print statement in the def post part, then this prints correctly the value of the ok_beschreibung field.

Do you have any idea what is the problem with the html output? I guess it is just a little detail that I am missing here.

PS: Here is also models.py

```
class OrgKlass(models.Model):
    ok_bezeichnung = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Org-Bezeichnung")
    ok_beschreibung = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Beschreibung des Tätigkeitsfeldes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ok_bezeichnung
   
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_from_object(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'OrgAna'
```

Comment: It does show the second field, but the value is *empty*.

Comment: But it is not empty in database. And the print statement from def post returns the correct output to the shell.

Comment: at that moment the object is *not* yet updated. That is done in the remainder of the `post` method.

Comment: Can you be so kind and explain this to me? I am still having difficulties with understanding the super statement. Is the line
return super(Update_Org, self).post(request, pk)
changing self.object.ok_beschreibung
?